# bootstrap dropdown button height is smaller than the main button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap drop down button but it's height is smaller than button

[image]

I don't wont to use  since I'm Using  already.
thanks in advance

Comment: You should add you css and html to the question.

Comment: I am using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">definition but dont wont to use 
<!DOCTYPE html >definition  since it solves the problem but cant use it for the seo concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Because you provide only image, so i can only provide bootstrap document

> http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

Please be sure you add class `btn-group` on wrapper div of dropdown button.

Try this: http://www.bootply.com/MincjjEhJw